# What is equivalent of php $_REQUEST in golang?

Tags: go, datatables

I am trying to implement datatables server-side-processing in golang with gin framework. I have my resource in php. I want to convert it into golang gin. Need a little help.

```php
// php codes
$params = $_REQUEST;
$draw = $params["draw"];
$orderColumn = $params['order'][0]['column'];
$sortColumnDir = $params['order'][0]['dir'];
```

```golang
// golang gin codes
// no idea what to do to get $_REQUEST as in php
// $params = $_REQUEST; // here what will be go code in gin ?
// I have tried following, but not sure
draw := c.Request.Form.Get("draw")
orderColumn := c.Request.Form.Get("order[0][column]")
sortColumnDir := c.Request.Form.Get("order[0][dir]")
```

Comment: _"I have tried following, but not sure"_ What was the result? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I am expecting the values that can be found from $_REQUEST (in php). So I need the golang gin edition of $_REQUEST to read the values. @icza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Stop thinking about `$_REQUEST`. Simply forget it exists. There is luckily no such thing in Go (for various reasons), and will never be.
2. Read the docs; figure out that `c.Request` [is actually a
   `http.Request`](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/f98b339b773105aad77f321d0baaa30475bf875d/context.go#L45).
3. Read [its docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request),
   figure out its `Form` field is an `url.Values`.
4. Read [its docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values), figure out it's a map of keys which are names of query parameters to slices of the arguments of these parameters.
5. Armed with that knowledge, in your request processing code, dump the whole contents of the `c.Request.Form` somewhere (that depends on how you run your server — if you fire it off right in a terminal for testing, then a simple `log.Print(c.Request.Form)` will suffice).

   Study what's there.
6. Work from there.